# Can we clean up the flag comment dialog a bit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment-flags

Since the SO designers and developers have been updating the look of the site lately, I wanted to see if we could also tweak the flag comment dialog box a bit, so the OCD side of me can rest easier.

In the current dialog, the close button is too close to the text "I am flagging this comment as", and the "as" is bumped down to the next line like this:

[image]

I'd suggest that the box be made a little wider to both keep thge "as" on the same line with the rest of the text and at the same time move the close button a little farther away like this:

[image]

Aaaah, much better.

While we're at it, should the text "I am flagging this comment as" have a colon at the end?

Comment: test comment (flag me and click cancel)